# Jasper report : How can i pass jasper report conditional parameter in java file?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

for example i would like to get 10 record out of 50 then how i can pass conditional parameter.
condition is like that.....

```
HashMap<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
params.put("id","id");
```

when i m pass conditional parameter report in java file at that time no error generate but generate blank report.

Comment: Did you pass the datasource? Are you using report without datasource (empty datasource)?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much of a clue.  Perhaps you mean:

```
params.put("id", id)
```

not

```
params.put("id", "id")
```